# How to configue a DNS server statically?

Tags: server, networking, dns, interface, resolv.conf

I am setting up an Ubuntu (12.04) Server with a single statically-configured network interface. Every time I reboot `/etc/resolv.conf` seems to get reset to empty. Where can I put my DNS server address?

Answer (score 2):

I've just found the answer - it is to add `dns-nameservers` line to `/etc/network/interfaces` as described [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/resolvconf.8.html).

Answer (score 1):

A good general overview to DNS in 12.04 is here: http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/